# jOOQ: Getting only one result instead of all existing entries

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I am having this call with jOOQ:

```
List<StoreRecord> fetchInto = this.ctx
        .select(Store.STORE.NAME)
        .from(Store.STORE)
        .join(StoreAdminStore.STORE_ADMIN_STORE)
            .on(StoreAdminStore.STORE_ADMIN_STORE.ID.eq(id))
        .where(Store.STORE.ID.eq(StoreAdminStore.STORE_ADMIN_STORE.STORE_ID))
        .fetchInto(StoreRecord.class);

for (StoreRecord store: fetchInto) {
    LOGGER.debug(store.getName());
}
```

Which should replicate this PostreSQL statement:

```
SELECT
  store.name
FROM store
  JOIN store_admin_store ON store_admin_store.store_admin_id = 1
WHERE store.id = store_admin_store.store_id
```

However, jOOQ delivers me a list with only *one* `StoreRecord` even though there are five entries which fit the certain criteria here..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `.join(...).on(...).where(...)` and replace it with `.where(Store.STORE.ID.eq(1))`?

Comment: @Ruslan Turns out it was just a stupid mistake on my side ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jOOQ query and your SQL query are not the same.

jOOQ query:

```
-- Is
STORE_ADMIN_STORE.ID.eq(id)

-- Should be
STORE_ADMIN_STORE.STORE_ADMIN_ID.eq(id)
```

SQL query:

```
store_admin_store.store_admin_id = 1
```

As it is right now, your query returns only one row from the relationship table (`ID = 1`) and then joins only the single relevant store to it.

Apart from that, you should probably switch predicates between the `ON` clause and the `WHERE` clause. Right now, you put the join predicate in the `WHERE` clause, whereas the filter predicate is in the `ON` clause...

Comment: *awkward* Yep, that was clearly a preventable mistake here .. Looked at it over and over but I didn't see the mistake. Thank you, Lukas!

Comment: @StefanFalk: It happens to the best :)